# How to create a custom property on an object by pressing UI button?

Tags: python, add-on

I'm writing a tool with a very simple panel with buttons.

On pressing a button a custom property with a specific name is to be assigned to the active object.

The UI should have 2 buttons **Target** and **Clear**

- Pressing **Target** button in the UI should create a custom property.
- Pressing **Clear** button in the UI should delete customer property that was created by the **Target** button (if such customer property is present).

For example, I have Cube and Sphere (names) objects. I would select Cube, then Sphere, press **Target** button, and Cube will have custom property names "target" with value "Sphere".

Selecting both of them in any manner and pressing **Clear** button would remove that custom property.

How do I go about making such basic add-on?

EDIT: Here is a mock-up that should explain it all :)

[image]

Link to full screen image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWyLc.png

Comment: Question isnt really clear about whats needed, is this about creating custom properties, or creating UI's?... How do I write an addon that does ***** is likely too vague for a question. Also did you try to do this already? - if so, what was the issue that stopped you from getting it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems to be asking for an add-on to be written from scratch? which is too specific.

The answer is yes, this is possible.

- Create an addon (see addon template).
- Create a panel, (see template for making a panel).
- Create an operator (see templates for creating those)
- The operator can assign a custom property, see the Quick Start section on [Custom Properties](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/info_quickstart.html#custom-properties)

So all of this is documented, best try to put this together to write your add-on.

Note, to access templates, see:
**Text Editor (Header) -> Templates -> Python**

Comment: Where do I find all the templates and documentation?

Comment: Edited answer to include *"how to access templates"*.

Answer (score 5):

you want [*ID properties*](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_quickstart.html#custom-properties), they can be set per object

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['whatever']
obj['some_property_name'] = 'some_value'
obj['some_property_name_2'] = 33

>>> obj['some_property_name_2']
... 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of adding Custom Properties from an Blender Add-on.  It can be modified to remove the properties as well: https://github.com/MarioDelgadoSr/AddBlenderCustomPropertiesFromCSV

Comment: please always include the relevant code in your answer. Links are always bound to become invalid over time.